# Laravel 8 - ajax removing first row

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm beginner in Ajax and I'm using Laravel 8. I want to remove row that from database but when I try this code it's removing first row but it needs to remove the returned id row. How can I remove the row?

**My blade is:**

```
<div class="anime__review__item" id="testp" >

     <div class="anime__review__item__pic">
            <img src="<?=url('/')?>/images/avatars/{{$comment->user->photo}}" alt="">
     </div>

     <div class="anime__review__item__text" >
        <h6><a href="{{route('getProfile', ['username'=> $comment->user->username])}}" >{{$comment->user->name }}</a></a><span >{{$comment->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</span></h6>
                                       
        <p> {{$comment->comment }}</p>

        <p class="card-text"><span class="icon_trash" type="button" data-id="{{ $comment->id }}" data-target="#default{{ $comment->id }}"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My ajax is:**

```
$(".icon_trash").click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
   
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {

                $.ajax({
                        url: "{{ route('deleteComments',['id' => $comment->id]) }}",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                            id: id
                        },
                        
                        success: function (){
                            
                                $("#testp").remove();
                                },
                                
                            error: function(){
                                alert('errorr');
                            },
                        })
        }
    })
});
```

**My controller is:**

```
public function deleteComments($id){
        $deletedata= Comment::findOrFail($id);
        $deletedata->delete();


        if($deletedata){
            return response()->json(['status'=>'testss']);
        }else{
            return back();
        }
}
```

Comment: Could I request you to once again share the controller code?

Comment: i updated @nice_dev

Comment: Ok, controller code looks fine. It should be deleting the ID you passed in your URL as `deletecomments/2` (taking an example).

Comment: actually it works fine. because when I removing row removing first arrow but when I reload page removing the ID row. I guess problem is in ajax. success function not working exactly

Comment: Aren't you fixing the id of the comment when creating the URL?  I guess you need to pass the id  you´re getting from the `"$(this).data("id");"` instead of `"$comment->id"` .

Comment: @reedus6749 That's confusing. Could you break it down further?

Comment: okay. for example: you have 2 row. you want to remove second row. you are removing second row but with this ajax code first row removing. that's wrong. whichever row you remove, it should be removed. but when you reload page the row you really want to delete has been deleted. I hope I could explain @nice_dev

Comment: not working @HéctorWilliam

Comment: @reedus6749 Ok, makes sense now, you will need to check with which row you delete as in remove from the DOM. Backend code works fine. Something related to `$("#testp").remove();` I believe.

Comment: yes but how can I check? I got stuck at this point :)

Comment: Can you show your frontend code using https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/

Comment: Can you share the outgoing request from your network devtool?

Comment: i updated in post. @nice_dev

Comment: @reedus6749 All divs have same ID `testp`?

Comment: yes. is it problem? @nice_dev

Answer (score 1):

Since all divs have same ID, you have this issue. To solve, have unique IDs  and unique removals as below:

- Have dynamic value for div ID as:

  ```
  <div class="anime__review__item" id="testp_{{ $comment->id }}">
  ```
- Remove the respective ID accordingly in your ajax code as:

  ```
  $("#testp_{{ $comment->id }}").remove();
  ```

This way, you correctly remove the parent div of the respective deleted comment.

Comment: @reedus6749 Glad I could help. Since you are new to SO, I would suggest always posting a minimum reproducible example of your code to get help much faster. Rest is fine.

Comment: i tried different way with the code now. when I have multiple row and I tried remove any row it is removing just last record. after then when I'm trying remove any row error function is working. can you help me again? @nice_dev

Comment: @reedus6749 That is unlikely. Like I said before, you will have to show a minimum verifiable example for me to reproduce the issue at my end. Isn't all these divs getting created in a loop?

Comment: I apologize for my inexperience in stackoverflow. yes all these divs getting creating in a loop.

Comment: @reedus6749 Can you confirm if all divs have unique IDs?

Comment: I did not understand what you said :( @nice_dev

Comment: Do all divs have different IDs?

Comment: no. all divs have same id. actually it has just a ID name. id name is 'testp_{{comment->id}}' as you know

Comment: @reedus6749 All IDs should have unique IDs for this solution to work. Sorry to say, I don't follow your HTML structure along with your blade code file anymore.